# Run a loop again

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, primes

I am trying to rerun a loop in python when it's on the last iteration but it's not working. Here's my code:

```
primes = [i for i in range(2, 1001)]
p = 2
for i in range(p, len(primes), p):
    primes[i] = 0
    if i == len(primes)-1 and (p+1) <= max(primes):
        p += 1
        print(p)
print(primes)
```

The code only runs once as the `print(primes)` shows that every 2nd value is made 0. I want it to rerun until p is not equal to the maximum value in the list.

Comment: You manipulate the step width of `range(p, len(primes), p)` *inside the `for` loop? Why?

Comment: If you want to do a bunch of statements multiple times, you put it in a loop. If you want to do a loop a bunch of times, you put it in *another* loop. Try to see what the outer loop should do. You'll also need to change and remove some of the code in your inner loop.

Comment: I want to keep the complexity `n` only.

Comment: Manipulating p won't change the the step of the loop. range has already returned the enumerator (if you're using python 3) that will have its values assigned to i.

Comment: 1st argument of `range` is start point and 3rd argument of it is step size. So you are starting from `p` and stepping by `p`.

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui: Well, you can't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
primes = [2, 3]
upto = 1000
for num in range(4, upto+1):
    if all(num % p for p in primes):
        primes.append(num)

print(primes)
```

Note that this could still be improved by not testing for division by primes > sqrt(num)